# How do you lift noise, as needed in Regularity structure?

Tags: soft-question, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am trying to learn about regularity structure. In the mini course part 1 and part 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgLW6dxl0IU Dr. Martin Hairer has mentioned several times about lifting noise. May I ask what does lifting noise mean? How it is done? I understand lift as mentioned in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lift.html

Can anyone please expalin a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a regularity structure $\mathcal{T}$ indexed by trees and a noise $\xi$, in order to leverage the fixed point theory at the level of modelled distributions, we want to associate to $\xi$ a model $(\Pi, \Gamma)$ (i.e. "lift" $\xi$ to a model). Of course, that model should preserve the relevant properties of $\xi$ from the perspective of solving the equation.

If $\xi$ is a smooth driving noise, then there is a very natural way to do this, known as the canonical lift. Namely, one sets
\begin{align*}
\Pi_x \Xi = \xi, \qquad \Pi_x X = (\cdot - x), \qquad \Pi_x \tau_1 \tau_2 = \Pi_x \tau_1 \cdot \Pi_x \tau_2
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\Pi_x \mathcal{I}\tau = K \ast \Pi_x \tau - \sum_{|k| < |\mathcal{I} \tau|} \frac{X^k}{k!} D^k K \ast \Pi_x \tau(x)
\end{align*}
where $K$ is the Green's kernel of your differential operator (up to a cut-off which is done for technical reasons, see [Hai14, section 5]). The last definition might look a little strange since $\mathcal{I} \tau$ was meant to represent the convolution of $\tau$ with the Green's kernel so you might have expected that $\Pi_x \mathcal{I}\tau = K \ast \Pi_x \tau$. However, this definition does not fulfil definition of a model since it need not be the case that
\begin{align*}
|K \ast \Pi_x \tau(\phi_x^\lambda)| \le C \lambda^{|\tau| + \beta}
\end{align*}
where $\beta$ is the degree by which $K$ is regularising (so e.g. for the heat kernel, $\beta = 2$). The sum we subtract off is then nothing other than the required Taylor jet to enforce this vanishing condition. The $\Gamma$ maps are then recursively constructed in a similar fashion. I write $\mathcal{L}(\xi)$ for $(\Pi, \Gamma)$ constructed in this way.

With this definition, the classical solution map $S_c: \xi \mapsto u$ which sends a choice of smooth driving noise to the solution of the corresponding equation can be factorised as $S_c \xi = \mathcal{R} S_a \mathcal{L}(\xi)$ where $\mathcal{R}$ is the reconstruction map and $S_a$ is the solution map for the abstract fixed point problem on the space of modelled distributions.

Of course, we wanted all of this machinery since we are interested in driving noises which aren't smooth and are in fact distributions of negative Holder regularity. Then there is no canonical lift since $\Pi_x \tau_1 \tau_2$ can't be defined by naively taking the product since that need not be well-defined. In fact, defining the lift of these distributional driving noises is a very difficult problem that has taken multiple 100+ page papers to resolve completely.

Since $S_a$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are continuous in the choice of model, one might hope that if we start with a distributional driving noise and mollify it by a mollifier at scale $\varepsilon$ to obtain $\xi_\varepsilon = \rho_\varepsilon \ast \xi$ to obtain a smooth noise then $\mathcal{L}(\xi_\varepsilon)$ will converge as $\varepsilon \to 0$ (which would then guarantee that $S_c u_\varepsilon$ is convergent as $\varepsilon \to 0$). Unfortunately, this is usually not the case and one instead has to "renormalise" $\mathcal{L}(\xi_\varepsilon)$ in a way that depends on the law of $\xi_\varepsilon$ to obtain a convergent sequence. This task is very involved but is by now well-understood. The paper [BHZ] provides a general algebraic recipe for renormalising models and the paper [ChHa16] (and very recently, one of my papers with Martin [HS23]) show that the resulting renormalised models do converge as $\varepsilon \to 0$. However, if you are starting to learn regularity structures, I recommend against trying to understand these general results for now. It is better to look at e.g. [FH20, section 15.5] to see an example of the KPZ equation treated by hand.

---

[Hai14] M. Hairer, [A theory of regularity structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5113)

[BHZ] Y. Bruned, M. Hairer, L. Zambotti, [Algebraic Renormalisation of Regularity Structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08468)

[ChHa16] A. Chandra, M. Hairer, [An Analytic BPHZ Theorem for Regularity Structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08138)

[HS23] M. Hairer, R. Steele, [The BPHZ Theorem for Regularity Structures via the Spectral Gap Inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.10081)

[FH20] P. Friz, M. Hairer, [A Course on Rough Paths With an Introduction to Regularity Structures](https://hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf)